# Critical points of a function and whether they are local maxima, local minima, and saddle points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Critical points of a function and whether they are local maxima, local minima and saddle points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a97iq.jpg)

F(x) = 4 + 2xy + y^2

F(y) = 4 + x^2 + 2xy

F(xx) = 2y

F(yy) = 2x

F(xy) = 2x + 2y

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Tvp.jpg)

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far, in particular to start of, you should compute $f_x$ and $f_y$. There is very standard approach to this problem

Comment: So, to find the critical points.   Fx=0  ::  4 + 2xy + y^2 = 0  :::: this is where I’m stuck at, would y = x / 2

Comment: Once you set $f_x$ and $f_y$ to be zero, observe the symmetry of those equations in the sense that you can deduce $x=y$ or $x=-y$ sub them back in then you can find critical points

Comment: Is this right, so far, so the critical points are (2,2) and (-2, -2)

Comment: I’m pretty sure I did the first case wrong....is the only critical point (0,0) ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure I did the first case wrong....is the only critical point (0,0) ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xZBU.jpg)

Comment: I think it should be just $(2,-2)$ and $(-2,2)$ what you attached is correct as far as I can see

Comment: Ok, thank you very much